# Event with named function

Tags: javascript

I try to add an event listener on a button element. A named function with one argument is triggered on click. 
My problem is that the function is automatically triggered on page loading and is not working on click. What is the problem?
Is it possible to use an anonymous function while passing an argument to it?

I tried with an named function simply declared and stored in a variable, both don't work.
I tried with an anonymous function but I didn't find out how to pass an argument to it.

```
var tab = [-2, 1, 4];

function additionne(x){
    return x + 2;
}

function affiche(tab){
    alert(additionne(tab[0]));
    alert(additionne(tab[tab.length - 1]));
}

var bouton = document.getElementById('bouton');
bouton.addEventListener('click', affiche(tab));
```

I expect the event to be triggered on click and only then.
It is actually triggered only once, on page loading and not on click.

Comment: `bouton.addEventListener('click', affiche(tab));` ... this runs `affiche(tab)` immediately, rather than on click even ... there's a difference between passing a function as an argument and passing the result of calling a function as an argument ... you're doing the latter rather than the former

Comment: `bouton.addEventListener('click', ()=>affiche(tab));`

Answer (score 1):

By writing as `affiche(tab)` you call the function immediately. In order to pass it as a callback with arguments, you can use [`bind()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Function/bind) to bind scope and arguments.

```js
var tab = [-2, 1, 4];

function additionne(x){
    return x + 2;
}

function affiche(tab){
    alert(additionne(tab[0]));
    alert(additionne(tab[tab.length - 1]));
}

var bouton = document.getElementById('bouton');
bouton.addEventListener('click', affiche.bind(this, tab));
//                                           ^^^^   ^^^
//                                           scope  argument(s)
```

```html
<button id="bouton">Click me</button>
```

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

You need to wrap it in a function.

```js
var tab = [-2, 1, 4];

function additionne(x){
    return x + 2;
}

function affiche(tab){
    alert(additionne(tab[0]));
    alert(additionne(tab[tab.length - 1]));
}

var bouton = document.getElementById('bouton');
bouton.addEventListener('click', function() { affiche(tab);});
```

```html
<button id="bouton">Alert</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

addEventListener takes a callback **function** as the 2nd argument.
You should use

```
function () { ... }
```

Instead of

```
affiche(tab)
```

Which is a **function call** (and not a function)